# Catching COMException specific Error Code

Tags: c#, com

I'm hoping someone can help me. I've got a specific Exception from COM that I need to catch and then attempt to do something else, all others should be ignored. My error message with the Exception is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x800A03EC): Microsoft Office Excel
>   cannot access the file 'C:\test.xls'.
>   There are several possible reasons:

So my initial attempt was

```
try
{
 // something
}
catch (COMException ce)
{
   if (ce.ErrorCode == 0x800A03EC)
   {
      // try something else 
   }
}
```

However then I read a compiler warning:

> Warning   22  Comparison to integral
>   constant is useless; the constant is
>   outside the range of type
>   'int' .....ExcelReader.cs 629 21

Now I know the 0x800A03EC is the
HResult and I've just looked on MSDN
and read:

> HRESULT is a 32-bit value,
>   divided into three different fields: a
>   severity code, a facility code, and an
>   error code. The severity code
>   indicates whether the return value
>   represents information, warning, or
>   error. The facility code identifies
>   the area of the system responsible for
>   the error.

So my ultimate question, is how do I ensure that I trap that specific exception? Or how do I get the error code from the HResult?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to add a note. It's not very easy to reproduce this exception as I need a very specific configuration to do so, which I am working toward but I thought asking here might be quicker :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The ErrorCode should be an unsigned integer; you can perform the comparison as follows:

```
try {
    // something
} catch (COMException ce) {
    if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode == 0x800A03EC) {
        // try something else 
    }
}
```

Comment: so, from C# code, there's no way to do something like, `using WinErrorsOrWhatever` and then `if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode == E_UNEXPECTED_OR_WHATEVER)`?

Comment: The above works, but only when compiled in `unchecked` context. Otherwise the negative `ce.ErrorCode` will not convert happily to a positive `uint`. It's actually nicer to convert the other side of the `==` symbol, and say `if (ce.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x800A03EC)) { ... }`. See [an example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult.aspx).

Comment: Is this a framework bug then? Should Exception.HResult be defined as a uint?

Comment: @Tristan: I think it's declared like that because unsigned types are not CLS compliant.

Comment: Newer, working link for the comment above: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.hresult

Answer (score 10):

An HRESULT value has 32 bits divided into three fields: a severity code, a facility code, and an error code. The severity code indicates whether the return value represents information, warning, or error. The **facility code** identifies the area of the system responsible for the error. The **error code** is a unique number that is assigned to represent the exception. Each exception is mapped to a distinct HRESULT.
*Excerpt from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT*

From what I gather, the first half of the HRESULT bits may change depending on the system/process that causes the exception. The second half contains the error type.

Code should look like:

```
try {
    // something
} catch (COMException ce) {
    if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode & 0x0000FFFF == 0x800A03EC) {
        // try something else 
    }
}
```

NOTE: please keep in mind I'm not a .NET guy, so be weary of syntax errors in the above code.

Comment: +1 : Thanks for the detailed breakdown. It's something from quite a while ago, but useful for anyone else who's interested.

Comment: What's the `& 0x0000FFFF` for? It will 'delete' (set to 0) the left half of the uint, so it can never be `== 0x800A03EC`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to get it running on the system I needed and found the error code was -2146807284.

Looking at that, if I convert the 0x800A03EC to Binary, then treat it as 2's compliment, then you can calculate the value.

Comment: Yes, the alternative is to convert the HRESULT to a signed integer, but maybe leaving the hex code makes it more readable (and easier to google).