# Weird warning converting VB.NET to C# - Hexadecimal Constants

Tags: c#, vb.net, warnings, vb.net-to-c#

I don't usually deal with hexadecimal numbers unless I am working with HTML, so I really do not have much experience converting code that involves them.  Essentially, the problem here is that I am converting some classes from VB.NET to C#.NET and there are a couple places where the VB version is comparing some value to a Hex constant.  When I translate the value to its C# equivalent, I get the following "warning" message from Visual Studio:

> Comparison to integral constant is useless, the constant is outside
>   the range of type 'int'

Now, obviously the VB version does not have this warning or I wouldn't bother asking this question.  I will note that if I cast the Property being compared as Int64 the warning goes away.

What I want to know is whether I have done this right and if I shouldn't just scrap the whole comparison since it apparently will not work in a real-world scenario?

VB Code:

```
    Catch ex As COMException
        If bInsert AndAlso ex.ErrorCode = &H80042776 Then
            ' DO THINGS
    End Try
```

C# Code:

```
        catch (COMException come)
        {
            if (insert && come.ErrorCode == 0x80042776)
            {
                // DO THINGS
            }
        }
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120512/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this has worked in VB.NET (not sure of the rules there), but C# will not easily let you specify a negative number like that. I think you have to say

```
...    come.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80042776)
```

Otherwise C# will not regard it as a negative 32-bit integer, I'm afraid. Even if your code is already compiled in `unchecked` context (which I bet it is!), you still have to write `unchecked` explicitly like above, when it's a compile-time constant you're "converting".

Irritating when 8 hex digits fit nicely to 32 bit (`System.Int32`).

Comment: is that equivalent to casting `COMException.ErrorCode` as `uint`?

Comment: @Matt Yes, but only in `unchecked` context. My way is most safe. I just added a comment to the answer to the other question you found.

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET, when it comes to [integer literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711649.aspx):

> values outside the range for Integer are typed as Long

Comment: Wouldn't the ErrorCode of the COMException object still be limited to the Int32 constraints? (Or whatever the default implmentation of the "Integer" type in VB is)  Or does the Integer type in VB also become "Long/Int64" if the value doesn't fit?

Answer (score 2):

COMException::ErrorCode is of type int32. So it's biggest value is 2^31 - 1. (2,147,483,647).

You are comparing with a hex number 0x80042776. With a decimal value of 2,147,755,894.

These numbers are pretty close, but notice that the hex one is bigger than the biggest number an int32 can possibly be. That's what the compiler is warning you about. The same is true in VB, it's just that the compiler isn't warning you about it.

Where did the magic hex constant come from? It's probably wrong.

Comment: The constant comes from some source code for a Kofax Capture Export Connector.  There's no explanation as to what it is supposed to mean so I really don't know why it is in there.

Comment: In many areas there's a rule to always interpret the hex number as a negative one if the leading digit is `8` through `F`, and then his constant is _inside_ the range of our signed `Int32`. The problem is that C# does not use that convention here. See my answer.

Comment: In vb.net, hex constants in the range &h80000000 to &hFFFFFFFF are interpreted as signed integers in the absence of a trailing type specifier of `ui`, `l`, `ul`, or `&`.  Much as I like vb.net, I find this behavior annoying, especially since *it applies even when the numbers are written with a leading zero*!  Actually, I'd like to see languages perform handle computations "as if" the operands were `Int64`, but recognize in what cases the upper portions can be skipped.  It's irksome that `longVar = longVar And Not 0x40000000` works, as does `longVar = longVar And Not 0x100000000`, but...

Comment: ...`longVar = longVar and 0x80000000` fails; the C# equivalents of these statements exhibit similar behavior.  Icky.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I did some additional searching on the issue (probably should have done this first), and found the answer I was looking for.  It turns out that COMException's ErrorCode is actually an UNSIGNED integer (see HRESULT).  Maybe VB automatically handles this, too?

The stack overflow post I saw that detailed this is here:  [Catching COMException specific Error Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426147/catching-comexception-specific-error-code) - look at the chosen answer to the question

I would like to hear back from other people about this one before I mark an answer.

Comment: To .NET, the `ErrorCode` is a _signed_ `Int32`, but it can be cast (of course) to an unsigned one. See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception.errorcode.aspx). The `COMException` class inherits its `ErrorCode` from `ExternalException`.